# Expand tkinter widget when enlarging window with scrollbar

Tags: tkinter, widget, scrollbar, frame

I have a LabelFrame and some Labels inside it.
I'd like to vertically scroll over Labels, and it works.
I'd like to horizontally enlarge the window, and the widget to enlarge consequently, but it does not work. I should use `frameTwo.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')` as in the comment, but the scrollbar does not work, anymore.

Could someone help me?

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

container = tk.Frame(root)

container.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')


canvas = tk.Canvas(container)
scroll_y = tk.Scrollbar(container, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)

frameTwo = tk.Frame(canvas)
# group of widgets

stepOne = tk.LabelFrame(frameTwo, text=" 1. This is my test")
stepOne.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=0, sticky='nsew')

for i in range(20):
    tk.Label(stepOne, text='label %i' % i).grid(row=i, column=0, pady=2, sticky='nsew')

# put the frame in the canvas

canvas.create_window(0, 0, anchor='nw', window=frameTwo)
# make sure everything is displayed before configuring the scrollregion
canvas.update_idletasks()

canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all'), 
                 yscrollcommand=scroll_y.set)

canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
scroll_y.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')

root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
#frameTwo.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
frameTwo.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
canvas.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```